# Blackberry upload file to web server

Tags: file, blackberry, upload

How to upload .doc file from blackberry mobile to web server like resume attachment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to upload the file through http to the website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788554/how-to-upload-the-file-through-http-to-the-website)

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to [link you to a question I answered earlier today.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788554/how-to-upload-the-file-through-http-to-the-website/2789649#2789649)  You just open a FileConnection to the .doc file, open a HttpConnection to the web server and read from the InputStream of FileConnection then write that to the OutputStream of the HttpConnection.