# how to upload the file through http to the website? (Blackberry)

Tags: blackberry, jde

I need to upload a file through http or ftp to the website in blackberry jde.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

High level view: You open an OutputStream from an [HttpConnection](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2.1api/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html) and write your data into that output stream.  The main problem is going to be choosing which network connection to use (I recommend looking at [this, unless you're on OS 5.0 which has a similar feature built in)](http://www.versatilemonkey.com/blog/index.php/2009/06/24/networking-helper-class/).  As to uploading through FTP that will be somewhat more difficult as there is no support for FTP built into the BlackBerry API instead you'll have to look at using a [SocketConnection](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.2.1api/index.html) and implementing part of FTP yourself.

Here's some code to get you started:

```
HttpConnection httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open("<URL>");
FileConnection fileConn = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///<path>");
InputStream in = fileConn.openInputStream();
OutputStream out = httpConn.openOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
int bytesRead = 0;
while((in.read(buffer) = bytesRead) > 0)
{
   out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Of course you'll need to deal with exceptions, close the streams, check that it was uploaded successfully, etc

Comment: I could be wrong, but this won't work on a HTTP form post. You still need to have the HTTP headers like type and length as well as a boundary string. Right?

Comment: Is there exists some limit for length of data in `InputStream in`?